# ConfidentialClientApplication AcquireTokenSilentAsync always fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I'm trying to use the OpenIdConnectAuthentication against the microsoft authority.  I'm able to authenticate, but when try to obtain an access token, the call fails, wanting me to re authenticate, which I do.  I seems to never pull the proper tokens.  Here is the code for the obtaining the access token.

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
{
    string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    //string signedInUserID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
    tokenCache = new MSALSessionCache(
        signedInUserID,
        HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase);
    var cachedItems = tokenCache.ReadItems(appId); // see what's in the cache

    ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
        appId,
        redirectUri,
        new ClientCredential(appSecret),
        tokenCache);

    try
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' }));
        return result.Token;
    }

    // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
    catch (MsalSilentTokenAcquisitionException)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
            new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
            OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        //throw new Exception("Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded");
        return null;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what I am missing.  I've used the Microsoft Graph REST ASPNET Connect sample to guide me so far.  My end goal is to authenticate the user, and then use some items from their profile and the MS rest api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to track this down.  Because I was using both the Asp.net Identity auth and the UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication, I had to add the external login claims to the ClaimsPrincipal manually.  This i what my ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl) look like:

```
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (loginInfo == null)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Login");
        }

        // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
        var result = await SignInManager.ExternalSignInAsync(loginInfo, isPersistent: false);

        logger.Info(loginInfo.Email + " attempted an external login with a result of " + result.ToString());

        switch (result)
        {
            case SignInStatus.Success:                  
                foreach (Claim c in loginInfo.ExternalIdentity.Claims)
                {
                    SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim(c.Type + "_external", c.Value));
                }

                var user = UserManager.FindById(SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.AuthenticationResponseGrant.Identity.GetUserId());

                user.LastLogin = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
                await UserManager.UpdateAsync(user);

                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
                return View("Lockout");
            case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
                return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = false });
            case SignInStatus.Failure:
            default:
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { Email = loginInfo.Email });
        }
    }
```

Because the external identity has a claim with a name that matches the asp.net identity, I had to rename the clams.  Then also adjust anywhere in code looking for the external identity claims.