# AcquireTokenSilentAsync not working because ConfidentialClientApplication has no users

Tags: c#, asp.net, owin, microsoft-graph-api, openid-connect

I'm having an issue with the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method and was hoping anyone could help me out.

In the method below im trying to use the `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` method so I can use it later to make a call to the Microsoft graph api. Unfortunately the Users property of the `ConfidentialClientApplication` is empty, as a result of that the `cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync` fails because it requires the first user in the parameter by calling `cca.Users.First()`.

```
public async Task<string> GetUserAccessTokenAsync()
    {
        string signedInUserID = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
        HttpContextWrapper httpContext = new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current);
        TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID, httpContext).GetMsalCacheInstance();

        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
            appId, 
            redirectUri,
            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
            userTokenCache,
            null);

        try
        {
            AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(scopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' }), cca.Users.First());
            return result.AccessToken;
        }

        // Unable to retrieve the access token silently.
        catch (Exception)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(
                new AuthenticationProperties() { RedirectUri = "/" },
                OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

            throw new ServiceException(
                new Error
                {
                    Code = GraphErrorCode.AuthenticationFailure.ToString(),
                    Message = Resource.Error_AuthChallengeNeeded,
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure why the `ConfidentialClientApplication` doesn't contain any Users, as the sign in at the start of the application works correctly. I am only using `UseCookieAuthentication` and `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` in the startup.

I hope anyone can help me with this problem!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ConfidentialClientApplication AcquireTokenSilentAsync always fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42035985/confidentialclientapplication-acquiretokensilentasync-always-fails)

Comment: @MarcLaFleur I've noticed this thread but the solution does seem to solve my issue aswell